# What is the easiest way to generate an html table in haskell

Tags: html, haskell

I would like to output a table in html format.
Basically I would like something like :

```
[[a]] -> <table>
```

What is the easiest way to do so ?

Comment: I don't understood what you are trying to say?

Comment: You should use a library to generate HTML like `blaze-html`.

Comment: `myTable xs = renderHtml $ table $ forM_ xs (tr . mapM_ (td . toHtml))`, if you were to use blaze, however, that's just from memory and could be wrong.

Comment: Seems that blaze is exactly what I want. What about an answer instead of a comment ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to generate Html is probably [blaze](http://jaspervdj.be/blaze/tutorial.html):

```
import Text.Blaze.Html5 (table, td, tr, toHtml, ToMarkup, Html)
import Control.Monad (forM_, mapM_)

myTable :: (ToMarkup a) => [[a]] -> Html
myTable xs = table $ forM_ xs (tr . mapM_ (td . toHtml))
```

Note that you need to use `renderHtml` from `Text.Blaze.Renderer.*` to get a `ByteString`, `String` or `Text`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** During writing the answer @Zeta already posted a better solution using `blaze-html`. So I recommend using his solution (see section "Words of Warning" for the listening of this solutions disadvantages...) ;-)

Here is an implementation:

```
-- file test.hs:

insideTag :: String -> String -> String
insideTag tag content = "<" ++ tag ++ ">" ++ content ++ "</" ++ tag ++ ">"

toTable :: Show a => [[a]] -> String
toTable = insideTag "table" . concatMap (insideTag "tr") . map (concatMap (insideTag "td" . show))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ toTable [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    return ()
```

The command `runhaskell test.hs` will now print

```
<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr></table>
```

### Explanation of the code

`insideTag` encapsulates content inside a html tag:

```
ghci> let insideTag tag content = "<" ++ tag ++ ">" ++ content ++ "</" ++ tag ++ ">"
ghci> insideTag "h1" "hello world"
"<h1>hello world</h1>"
```

`map (concatMap (insideTag "td" . show)) list` encapsulate the inner elements into `<td>` tags and concatenate them:

```
ghci> map (concatMap (insideTag "td" . show)) [[1,2], [3,4]]
["<td>1</td><td>2</td>","<td>3</td><td>4</td>"]
```

The same can be done for the outer list:

```
ghci> concatMap (insideTag "tr") ["<td>1</td><td>2</td>","<td>3</td><td>4</td>"]
"<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>"
```

The last string only has to be encapsulate into a `<table>` tag:

```
ghci> insideTag "table" "<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>"
"<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>"
```

### Words of warning

The above code uses the normal `[Char]` type for strings which is not memory efficient. So I recommend that you use [Data.Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) if you deal with big tables (`toTable` remains the same, you just have to change `show` to `pack . show`; `insideTag` has to reimplemented for `Data.Text`).

**There is also no HTML escaping for the table content!!!** So the above code is vulnerable to [XSS attacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). So do not use the above code, if the produced HTML shall be included in a website (especially if the website user has an influence on the table content)!